# Fermat+ related diophantine equation (afaik)

Tags: number-theory

Lets say for some $a,b,c$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $a^3+b^3+c^3=0$ and $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.  Now say for $a$ and $b$ $(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)+c^3=0$ and let $c^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ , then $ (a+c)^3-3ac(a+c)=(-b)^3 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ , since otherwise $\gcd(b,c)=3$ which is contradictory. 
Now that it is established, I think ,that there is a pair in which we can write WLOG as $(a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab)=(-c)^3$. We can say the two factors have no common divisor , that is $\gcd ((a+b),3ab)=1$.
Then lets say $(a+b)=x^3$ and $((a+b)^2-3ab)=y^3$. Then using some algebra solving for $b$ gives a discriminant which is of the form $12y^3-3x^6=n^2$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now we can say that $n^2-x^6 \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, thus $n-x^3$  is of form $2M$.
Solving for $M$ gives $M=-x^3\pm\sqrt{12y^3-3x^6}$.
Now this discriminant is also square but it is of the same form , so can we say there is no solution(Except for $a=0, b=c$ case which corresponds to $x=1=y$) ?

Comment: Ahh , seems i have just made a mistake , its not new information at the end

Comment: Do you mean $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$? Because $\gcd(a,b,c)=0 \Rightarrow a=b=c=0$

Comment: Yeah , sorry   Thats what i meant

Comment: Doesn't Fermat's Last Theorem make this impossible.  If $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 0, ~: ~0 \neq a,b,c$, then exactly two of the three are the same sign.  Without loss of generality $c < 0 < a,b \implies a^3 + b^3 = (-c)^3$ : this violates Fermat's Last Theorem : what am I missing?

Comment: @MehemmedYusifov Sir Andrew Wiles had proven it already. Check his proof.

Comment: For the case $n=3$ , there is a quite simple proof (we do not need Wiles for this). As far as I can see, this case covers the question and shows that there are no solutions.

Comment: I wanted to prove this by my own thats why this attemp was made